# Hyperparameter-tuning (Hyperas) and Cross-Validation with Pipeline-Preprocessing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, hyperas

**tl;dr I try to optimize and cross-validate my hyperparameters with Hyperas but can't make a preprocessing (scaling, over/undersampling) pipeline with KerasClassifier work**

I use [Hyperas](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) (wrapper for hyperopt) to tune my Neural Network's (built with Keras/Tensorflow) hyperparameters and try to implement a kfold-cross validation for optimal parameters. However, I also do preprocessing on the data (Standardscaler & MinMaxScaler) and then Over/undersampling using SMOTETOMEK).

I [read](https://github.com/maxpumperla/hyperas) that one should not do the feature scaling and resampling on the whole dataset but only on the parts that are used for training to avoid spillovers. Trying to implement this inside hyperopt only for the train folds of the cross-validation is somewhat difficult, because when using a pipeline like `imblearn`, the pipeline only works with KerasClassifier which only takes a model-function. I can't give him that model function because the whole validation process in hyperopt takes place in one function.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make something like this work? Can I do all the preprocessing in `def data()` and optimize/cross validate the parameters on the whole dataset or does this hurt the correct parameter finding process? (I do have an additional test dataset for the final model)

Is there a way to make it work manually?

```
def data():
    import pandas as pd
    import feather

    df_hyper_X = feather.read_dataframe('df_hyper_X_train.feather')
    df_hyper_Y = feather.read_dataframe('df_hyper_Y_train.feather')

    return df_hyper_X, df_hyper_Y

def hyper_model(df_hyper_X,df_hyper_Y):

  stdscl_features = ['pre_grade', 'math']
  normscl_features = 'time'
  stdscl_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('stdscaler', StandardScaler())])
  normscl_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[('normscaler', MinMaxScaler())])

  preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('stdscl', stdscl_transformer, stdscl_features),('minmaxscl', normscl_transformer, normscl_features)], remainder='passthrough')

  metrics = [
            tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
            tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
             ]

  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(Dense({{choice([2,4,8,16,32,64])}}, activation={{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])}}, kernel_initializer={{choice(['lecun_uniform','glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform'])}}
                  , input_shape=(16,))) #If ReLu use --> HE uniform initialization #kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2({{choice([0.01, 0.05, 0.1])}}
          #model.add(LeakyReLU(alpha={{uniform(0.5, 1)}}))
  model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))      
  if ({{choice(['one', 'two'])}}) == 'two':
      model.add(Dense({{choice([2,4,8,16,32,64])}}, activation={{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])}}))
      model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))

  #model.add(Dense({{choice([2,4,8,16,32,64])}}, activation={{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])}})) third hidden layer
  #model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))

  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  nadam = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adamax = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adagrad = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adadelta = tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  rmsprop = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})


  opti_choice = {{choice(['adam', 'nadam', 'adamax','adagrad', 'adadelta', 'sgd','rmsprop'])}}
  if opti_choice == 'adam':
      optimizer = adam
  elif opti_choice == 'nadam':
      optimizer = nadam
  elif opti_choice == 'adamax':
      optimizer = adamax
  elif opti_choice == 'adagrad':
      optimizer = adagrad
  elif opti_choice == 'adadelta':
      optimizer = adadelta
  elif opti_choice == 'sgd':
      optimizer = sgd
  else:
      optimizer = rmsprop

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

  kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=3)

  imba_pipeline = make_pipeline(preprocessor, SMOTETomek(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=2),
                                KerasClassifier(model, epochs={{choice([20,30,40,50,60,70])}}, batch_size={{choice([16,32, 64, 128])}}, verbose=0))
  results = cross_val_score(imba_pipeline, df_hyper_X, df_hyper_Y, cv=kfold, scoring='precision').mean()


  print('Precision', results)
  return {'loss': -results, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=hyper_model,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=30,
                                          trials=Trials(),
                                          notebook_name = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/final_NL_EU_Non-EU')
    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()
    print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
    print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    print(best_run)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it. This is the solution if anybody is interested:

```
def data():
    import pandas as pd
    import feather

    df_hyper_X = feather.read_dataframe('df_hyper_X_train.feather')
    df_hyper_Y = feather.read_dataframe('df_hyper_Y_train.feather')

    return df_hyper_X, df_hyper_Y

def hyper_model(df_hyper_X,df_hyper_Y):

  ct = ColumnTransformer([('ct_std', StandardScaler(), ['pre_grade', 'math']),('ct_minmax', MinMaxScaler(), ['time'])
  ], remainder='passthrough')

  metrics = [
            tf.keras.metrics.TruePositives(name='tp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalsePositives(name='fp'),
            tf.keras.metrics.TrueNegatives(name='tn'),
            tf.keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(name='fn'), 
            tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(name='accuracy'),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
            tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc'),
             ]

  model = tf.keras.Sequential()
  model.add(Dense({{choice([2,4,8,16,32,64])}}, activation={{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])}}, kernel_initializer={{choice(['lecun_uniform','glorot_normal', 'glorot_uniform', 'he_normal', 'he_uniform'])}}
                  , input_shape=(20,)))
  model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 0.5)}}))

  if ({{choice(['one', 'two'])}}) == 'two':
      model.add(Dense({{choice([2,4,8,16,32,64])}}, activation={{choice(['relu', 'sigmoid', 'tanh', 'elu', 'selu'])}}))
      model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 0.5)}}))

  model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

  adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  nadam = tf.keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adamax = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adagrad = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  adadelta = tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})
  rmsprop = tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr={{choice([0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1])}})

  opti_choice = {{choice(['adam', 'nadam', 'adamax','adagrad', 'adadelta', 'sgd','rmsprop'])}}
  if opti_choice == 'adam':
      optimizer = adam
  elif opti_choice == 'nadam':
      optimizer = nadam
  elif opti_choice == 'adamax':
      optimizer = adamax
  elif opti_choice == 'adagrad':
      optimizer = adagrad
  elif opti_choice == 'adadelta':
      optimizer = adadelta
  elif opti_choice == 'sgd':
      optimizer = sgd
  else:
      optimizer = rmsprop

  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)

  smt = SMOTETomek(sampling_strategy='auto', random_state=2)
  kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=3)  
  scores = []

  for train_fold_index, val_fold_index in kfold.split(df_hyper_X,df_hyper_Y):

    X_train_fold, y_train_fold = df_hyper_X.iloc[train_fold_index], df_hyper_Y.iloc[train_fold_index]

    X_val_fold, y_val_fold = df_hyper_X.iloc[val_fold_index], df_hyper_Y.iloc[val_fold_index]

    X_train_fold = ct.fit_transform(X_train_fold)
    X_val_fold = ct.transform(X_val_fold)

    X_train_smtk, y_train_smtk = smt.fit_resample(X_train_fold, y_train_fold)

    model.fit(X_train_smtk, y_train_smtk, epochs={{choice([20,30,40,50,60,70])}}, batch_size={{choice([16,32, 64, 128])}})

    predicts = model.predict(X_val_fold)
    score = precision_score(y_val_fold, predicts.round())
    scores.append(score)

  avg_score = np.mean(scores)    
  print('Precision', avg_score)
  return {'loss': -avg_score, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(model=hyper_model,
                                          data=data,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=2,
                                          trials=Trials(),
                                          notebook_name = 'drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/final_NL_EU_Non-EU')
    df_hyper_X, df_hyper_Y = data()
    print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    print(best_run)
```